# Setting date and time for a file name using C

Tags: c, time

I found an example to set date and time for a file. Can anyone explain what this loop:

```
for (; *p; ++p)
{
    if (*p == ' ')
          *p = '_';
}
```

...means?

```
/* ctime example */
    #include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
    #include <time.h>       /* time_t, time, ctime */

    int main ()
    {
      time_t rawtime;
      char buffer [255];

      time (&rawtime);
      sprintf(buffer,"/var/log/SA_TEST_%s",ctime(&rawtime) );
    // Lets convert space to _ in

    char *p = buffer;
    for (; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p == ' ')
              *p = '_';
    }



      printf("%s",buffer);
      fopen(buffer,"w");

      return 0;
    }
```

When I executed this program, the file name doesn't have `'_'` and instead it has empty spaces even though the program states that `' '` are replaced by `'_'`.

Comment: The loop converts blanks to underscores, so that the file name doesn't contain blanks.  But using the output of `ctime()` for a date format is a ghastly thought.  Use an ISO 8601 style date, such as `2018-03-12.12:34:56` or something similar, formatted using `strftime()`.  Also note that `ctime()` includes a newline at the end of the string; that is included in the file name — which is a very bad idea (it undoes any good that the blank-mapping did).

Comment: http://codepad.org/z16FBt5Q Looks like it works to me.  What is the exact output?

Comment: When I test the code, the blanks are replaced by underscores.  (I mapped the newline into a null byte and terminated the loop, but the underscores are mapped before that.)  I also deleted the line that creates the file; that isn't material to what the name look likes.

Comment: SA_TEST_Fri Mar 23 18:53:28 2018 is the output. In this the spaces are not replaced by the underscores.

Comment: Then the code you show above doesn't match what you are executing.  Could it be that you have a non-breaking space in the source code, which doesn't show when copied from above.  I copied the code and it *does* fix the spaces on a Mac running macOS 10.13.3 (High Sierra) with GCC 7.3.0.  Which system are you using?  Which compiler?  Have you tried copying the text from the question into a new file, and compiling and running that?  (I recommend removing the `fopen()` call; you don't need it while you're experimenting with what the loops do.)

Comment: Ya.. sorry, it was my mistake. I have replaced '  ' with '\0' in the program. Now it works when I reset it to ' '.

Comment: Space and `'\0'` are quite different.  Hopefully next time you will post the code you used, not the code you thought you used.

Answer (score 1):

If `p` is a pointer to a string, loop `for (; *p; ++p)` iterates over the characters of the string; note that condition `*p` means "as long as the value to which `p` currently points to is not equal 0 (i.e. the string termination character)", and that `++p` moves the pointer to the next character. 
Expression `if (*p == ' ') *p = '_'` simply means "if the current character is a blank, replace it with an `'_'`".

If your file name still contains "blanks", it might be the case that these blanks are not `' '` but other characters that shine as a blank (like, for example, a tab `'\t'`). You could use `if (isblank(*p)) *p = '_'` instead; and you could add `if (*p == '\n') { *p=0; break; }` in order to eliminate new lines and truncate the filename at such an occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

**This loop iterates through `buffer` to replace spaces by underscores.**

Explanation:

```
char *p = buffer; // `p` is a pointer to the beginning of `buffer`
for (; *p ; ++p) // Increment `p` to point to the next character, until a `\0` is reached
{
    if (*p == ' ') // Check if the character at pointer `p` is a space
        *p = '_'; // If so, replace it by an underscore
}
```